# Exact sequences of modules vs. exact sequences of Hom abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

I stumbled upon the following theorem in Dummit and Foote’s *Abstract Algebra*, Section 10.5:

> **Theorem 28.**
> Let $D$, $L$, $M$, and $N$ be $R$-modules.
> If
> $$
>   0
>   \longrightarrow L
>   \xrightarrow{\enspace \psi \enspace} M
>   \xrightarrow{\enspace \varphi \enspace} N
>   \longrightarrow 0
> $$
> is exact, then the associated sequence
> $$
>   0
>   \longrightarrow \mathrm{Hom}_R(D, L)
>   \xrightarrow{\enspace \psi' \enspace} \mathrm{Hom}_R(D, M)
>   \xrightarrow{\enspace \varphi' \enspace} \mathrm{Hom}_R(D, N)
>   \tag{10}
> $$
> is exact.
> A homomorphism $f \colon D \to N$ lifts to a homomorphism $F \colon D \to M$ if and only if $f ∈ \mathrm{Hom}_R(D, N)$ is in the image of $\varphi'$.
> In general $\varphi' \colon \mathrm{Hom}_R(D, M) \to \mathrm{Hom}_R(D, N)$ need not be surjective;
> the map $\varphi'$ is surjective if and only if every homomorphism from $D$ to $N$ lifts to a homomorphism from $D$ to $M$, in which case the sequence $(10)$ can be extended to a short exact sequence.
>
> The sequence $(10)$ is exact for *all* $R$-modules $D$ if and only if the sequence
> $$
>   0
>   \longrightarrow L
>   \xrightarrow{\enspace \psi \enspace} M
>   \xrightarrow{\enspace \varphi \enspace} N
> $$
> is exact.
>
> ([Original scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiZGM.jpg))

Let $R$ be a ring with $1$, not necessarily commutative. Let $D, L, M$ and $N$ be $R$-modules. If the sequence
$$
  0
  \longrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_R(D, L)
  \xrightarrow{\enspace g_* \enspace} \operatorname{Hom}_R(D,M)
  \xrightarrow{\enspace h_* \enspace} \operatorname{Hom}_R(D, N)
$$
is exact for all $R$-modules $D$, then $0 \to L \xrightarrow{g} M \xrightarrow{h} N$ is exact.

First observation is that since $R$ is not commutative, $\operatorname{Hom}_R(D, L)$ is generally not an $R$-module. So in general, the exact sequence of the homomorphisms is an exact sequence of abelian groups. But when I saw the proof, it used the fact that when using $R$ as an $R$-module instead of arbitrary $D$, $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R, L)$ is an $R$-module and also $\operatorname{Hom}_R(D, L) \cong L$ as $R$-module isomorphism. This part is clear to me.

My question is the following: If we consider $0 \to L \xrightarrow{g} M \xrightarrow{h} N$ to be an exact sequence of only the underlying structure of abelian groups, I understand why the theorem is true, but if the consequence is an exact sequence of modules, I don’t see how this result is true. I don’t see a straightforward way to convert $g_*$ from a group homomorphism into an $R$-module homomorphism  $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R, L) \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(R, M)$.

Edit: I need to be clearer about my question. My question is, for whoever is familiar with the theorem, what is the formulation of the theorem? Do we talk about the latter exact sequence as a sequence of modules or a sequence of groups? If it is a sequence of modules, then how can I prove it?

Comment: Whether a sequence is exact doesn't depend on what ring you are viewing it over, all that matters is that the individual homomorphisms are maps of $R$-modules. The image is the image, the kernel is the kernel, and the ring doesn't enter into it.  Here, you are given $g$ and $h$, which are assumed to be $R$-module homomorphisms.

Comment: OK, so this is exactly the question. How do I get from regular abelian group homomorphisms to R-module homomorphisms

Comment: $R$-module homomorphisms are just abelian group homomorphisms between $R$-modules that just so happen to commute with scalar multiplication.  So if you have maps between $R$-modules that are maps of abelian groups, they either are or are not $R$-module homomorphisms.  However, if you have maps between abelian groups, $\hom_{\mathbb Z}(R,A)$ $\hom_{\mathbb Z}(A,R)$, and $R\otimes_{\mathbb Z}A$ will all have actions of $R$ (though one of the first two is a right R-module instead of left, and I can't remember which one off the top of my head), yielding functors to $R$-modules.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I don't see how it answers my question. R is not necessarily a commutative ring, specifically not $Z$

Comment: I'm not terribly sure what your question is, because what you are asking at the end doesn't really make sense in the context of the proof you are talking about.  If $L$ and $M$ are only abelian groups, then it doesn't make sense to talk about $\hom_R(R,L)$, and if $L$ and $M$ are $R$-modules but the map between them is not an $R$-module homomorphism, then it is strange to apply the $\hom_R(R,-)$ functor, as you are applying it to something that isn't a morphism in the category.  But you can try to mimic the construction for when it is in the category to see if you still get an $R$-module map.

Comment: No, they are modules. I guess my question is, if the Theorem is correct and the sequence in the consequence is a sequence of modules, then how do I prove it? I can only prove it when we look at the consequence as an exact sequence of groups

Comment: Are you asking if I am this user on youtube? The answer is no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M,N,P$ be $R$-modules ($R$ unital, but necessariliy commutative) then $\hom_R(M,N)$ is a priori only an abeliean group (=$\mathbb{Z}$-module). I will provide a (partial) proof of your claim, namely that
$$0\to M \xrightarrow{f} N \xrightarrow{g} P \tag{1}$$
is exact iff for all $R$-modules $D$ the sequence
$$0\to \hom_R(D,M) \xrightarrow{f_*} \hom_R(D,N)\xrightarrow{g_*} \hom_R(D,P)\tag{2}$$
is exact.

Assume (1). First we'll show that $f_*$ is injective. We have that
$$\ker(f_*)=\ker(\hom_R(D,M)\to \hom_R(D,N))\cong\hom_R(D,\ker(M\to N))=0$$
(the isomorphism can either be computed directly or can be seen abstractly because the functor $\hom_R(D,-)$ commutes with arbitrary limits). As $g\circ f=0$ we have $g_* \circ f_* =0$, so $\operatorname{im} f_* \subset \ker g_*$ by functoriality of $\hom_R(D,-)$. Let $h\in \ker(g_*)\subset \hom_R(D,N)$, i.e. $g\circ h=0$, so for all $d\in D$ we have $h(d)\in \ker g=\operatorname{im}f$; pick $m_d\in M : f(m_d)=h(d)$ for $d\in D$ and define $\phi:D\to M, d\mapsto \phi(d):= m_d$. As $f$ is injective the $m_d$'s are unique. We claim that $\phi$ is $R$-linear. Indeed, let $\mu\in R, d,d'\in D$. By construction and $R$-linearity of $f$ and $h$ we get:
$$f(\phi(d+\mu d'))=h(d+\mu d')=h(d)+\mu h(d')=f(\phi(d)+\mu \phi(d')),$$
whence $\phi(d+\mu d')=\phi(d)+\mu \phi(d')$, since $f$ is injective.

Assume (2). Take $D=R$ in (2). This yields (1).

Comment: Thank you. One question though, for the only if statement, when you take $D=R$ how do you show that  $0\xrightarrow{}M\xrightarrow{\mathit{g}}N\xrightarrow{\mathit{h}}P$ is an exact sequence of modules? I could only show if for their group structure

Comment: Due to your other comments I think there is still some confusion left. When we write $\hom_R(M,N)$ then every element of this set is an $R$-linear map by its definition. And a sequence of $R$-modules with $R$-linear maps between them is exact iff the sequence of the underlying abelian groups is exact with linear maps between them because all you need to check are some assertions regarding Images or kernels of some maps. But the kernel (resp. image) of an $R$-linear map $f$ is the same as the kernel (resp. image) of the map induced by $f$ between the underlying abelian groups of the modules.

Comment: So what you say is that I should only care about exactness and not care at all if I am dealing with homomorphisms of R-modules or homomorphisms of only abelian groups? Would you agree that when we assume (2), then we can assume only an exact sequence of abelian groups?

Comment: @nilsw Hi! Can you please tell me which result you used to deduce  $hom_{R}( D, ker(M\to N))=0$in the 9th line of your answer?

Comment: @nilsw How does $g\circ f =0$ implies that  $g_* \circ f_* $=0?

Comment: @DTPW since $(-)_*$ is functorial and regarding your first question just note that $\hom(D,-)$ commutes with (finite) limits and in particular kernels.

Answer (score 4):

First we offer clarification on the statement of the theorem.

Suppose that $R$ is a (not necessarily commutative) associative ring $L, M, N\in R-\text{mod}$ (left $R$-modules, as without commutativity we must pick a side), and further suppose that $g:L\to M$ and $h:M\to N$ are $R$-module homomorphisms. For any $R$-module $D$, we have a functor $\hom_R(D,-):R-\text{mod}\to \mathbb Z-\text{mod}$, defined on morphisms by composition: if $g:L\to M$, then $g_*:\hom_R(D,L)\to \hom_R(D,M)$ is defined by $g_*(f)=g\circ f$.

It is not too difficult to show that if $0\stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} L\stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} M\stackrel{h}{\longrightarrow} N$ is a left exact sequence, then $0\longrightarrow \hom_R(D,L)\stackrel{g_*}{\longrightarrow} \hom_R(D,M)\stackrel{h_*}{\longrightarrow} \hom_R(D,N)$ is also left exact.

The theorem is the converse of this statement.  If $L, M, N, g, h$ are all given, and if for *every* choice of $D$ the sequence $0\longrightarrow \hom_R(D,L)\stackrel{g_*}{\longrightarrow} \hom_R(D,M)\stackrel{h_*}{\longrightarrow} \hom_R(D,N)$ is left exact, then $0\stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} L\stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} M\stackrel{h}{\longrightarrow} N$ is left exact.

There is NOTHING to prove about things being maps of $R$-modules, because things are assumed to be maps of $R$-modules.  The only things to prove are about exactness.

There isn't much to prove here, because you can simply take $D=R$, and there is a cannonical isomorphism $\hom_R(R,M)\cong M$ $f\mapsto f(1)$.  There is a corresponding theorem with the contravariant functors $\hom_R(-,D)$ which is more interesting.

---

However, it is worth spending a bit of time generalizing the fact that when $D=R$, we are getting not just abelian groups but $R$ modules.

Suppose that $D$ is an $(R,S)$-module (left $R$-module, right $S$-module, and the two structures commute with each other, i.e., $(rd)s=r(ds)$), then the hom-sets will carry more structure and the induced morphisms will be compatible with that structure.

If $D\in (R,S)-\text{mod}$ and $M\in R-\text{mod}$, then we can define multiplication $s\cdot f$ on $f\in \hom_R(D,M)$ by $(s\cdot f)(d)=f(ds)$.  Then $[(st)\cdot f](d)=f(dst)$ while $[s\cdot (t\cdot f)](d)=(t\cdot f)(ds)=f(dst)$

If $M$ and $N$ are $R$-modules and $g:M\to N$ is an $R$-module homomorphism, then the induced map is a map of $S$-modules.  We need to verify $g_*(s\cdot f)=s\cdot (g_*(f))$.  For every $d\in D$ we can evaluate and then unravel the definitions.  $g_*(s\cdot f)(d)=g\circ (s\cdot f)(d)=g(f(ds))=s\cdot (g(f(d))=[s\cdot (g_*(f))](d)$.

---

It is also worth remarking that if the map is not a map of $R$-modules, then the induced map will not exist (or rather, will not go between the required spaces).  Let $M, N\in R-\text{mod}$, and $g:M\to N$ be a map of abelain groups which is NOT a map of $R$-modules, so that there exists $m, r$ such that $g(rm)\neq rg(m)$.  If $f\in \hom_R(D,M)$, then $g\circ f$ will not in general be an $R$-module homomorphism.  Suppose that $f(d)=m$. Then $$r(g_*(f))(d)=r[(g\circ f) (d)]=r(g(f(d)))=r(g(m))\neq g(rm)=g(rf(d))=[g_*(rf)](d).$$

Comment: I see, thank you for the elaborate answer. So I can assume that in the converse, i.e., the direction I posted, that $hom_R(D,L)$, $hom_R(D,M)$, $hom_R(D,N)$ are always left $R-$ modules and $g_*$ and $f_*$ are their respective $R-$module homomorphisms?

Comment: @User666x No, they are only R modules if $D$ is a bi-module.  Further, $g_*$ and $h_*$ do not come out of nowhere, they are specifically induced from $g$ and $h$ which already exist.

Comment: Also, $g_*$ isn't one single morphism.  For every choice of $D$ you get different $g_*$.  You need to be very careful here about how things are being quantified.  $L, M, N, f, g$ are given, and then for every choice of $D$ you have a result.  The proof only uses one of those choices ($D=R$), but the statement requires "every" because it is half of an if and only if statement.

Comment: Yes of course, I understand that $g_*$ is not one single morphism. But I still have the same problem. If apriori I don't know that $hom_R(D,L)$, $hom_R(D,M)$, $hom_R(D,N)$, are $R-$modules, then how can I have the consequence that $g$ and $f$ will be module homomorphisms? And also what do you mean by $g_*$ is induced by $g$? On the converse, I start with $g_*$ and need to show existence for $g$, this was my problem in the first place.

Comment: Again, $g$ and $h$ are module homomorphisms by assumption.  Not only did I state that explicitly (hence the clarification on the question, but also why I put the final paragraph about how if they weren't module homomorphisms then you wouldn't even have $g_*$ and $h_*$ to begin with.  You do NOT start with $g_*$, you start with $g, h$ and a PROPERTY of $g_*, h_*$ and you need to show a corresponding property for $g, h$.  You are fundamentally misunderstanding what you are given in the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and explanations

Comment: Aaron, in my version of the Theorem, I am not given $g$ and $h$. I am only given the exact sequence of Hom and I need to show that exists $g$ and $h$ such that the sequence of $L, M, N$ is exact. My problem is that I cannot show the $g$ and $h$ are R-module homomorphisms

Comment: @User666x I will need you to attach a picture, as I do not believe you. What you are saying is that for every D there is $g_*, h_*$ that a priori have absolutely no relationship to each other as D changes, and that is patently absurd. It is far more likely that you misunderstand than it is the statement is anything resembling what you claim.

Comment: You are right. I will post the theorem directly from the book as a photo. Thank you

Comment: I added the photo

Comment: @User666x It is exactly as I said.  You are starting with a sequence of $R$-modules and $R$-module homomorphisms, for every $D$ you have an induced sequence of abelian groups and group homomorphisms, and you are showing that the original sequence is left-exact if and only if the induced sequence is always left-exact.  You have simply misunderstood what you have been given (and possibly the definition of the induced map?)